# Magento 2 gradually slows down throughout the day

Tags: pagespeed, browser, slowbackend

I am using Magento 2.3.1 and gradually throughout a day our website will slow way down on a specific browser. If we switch browsers or computers it will be working fine again, but after some time it will gradually begin to slow down again. This is the case for Chrome, Edge and Firefox. If we clear our browser cache and Magento 2 cache, it does not fix the issue. The next day it starts all over again. It affects both the frontend and the backend. I've checked our server resources and they are not bogged down. All other websites load quickly, but ours will not. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Please try to run **php bin/magento cache:enable** command once

Comment: Cache is already enabled

Comment: Are you running update by save or update by schedule? (latter is better)

Comment: I changed index management to update on schedule. I'll monitor for the day and see how it goes

Comment: Also check if you run continuously Javascript, jquery functions running with interval and gradually require more and more ram.

Comment: @pontikos how can I go about checking this?

Comment: @Josiah well you should generally for js memory leak. I would first search for ```setInterval``` function in my code. And wonder if me or my team added something lately to the website. Generally what else happened when this issue appeared and believe me even the silliiest change.